# Always getting "unread result found" error in python SQL in first iteration of loop

Tags: python, mysql, exception, mysql-connector-python

I am using mysql-connector-python 8.0.33 and tring to fetch all records from database using following code .

```
def retrieve_records():
    try:
        cursor = conn.cursor(buffered= True)
        cursor.execute(f"SELECT * FROM {scanner.table_name}")
        records = cursor.fetchall()
        tree.delete(*tree.get_children())

        for record in records:
            tree.insert("", "end", values=record)

        while cursor.nextset():
            pass  # Consume any remaining unread result sets

        cursor.close()
    except mysql.connector.Error as err:
        messagebox.showerror("Error", f"An error occurred while retrieving the records: {err}")
```

I am calling following function in a loop and there is an issue. Every time when I run the program and the loop is executed very first time I get **Unread result found** error every time. In short it goes to exception block in every first iteration.

[image]

Basically my **program scan the qr code and store it to database and show the data in json decoded format on UI** and here is one feature that if there is data in database already it should load it in list first. But not working it is giving error as mentioned above.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Credencys\Desktop\qr\app.py", line 196, in <module>
    retrieve_records()
  File "C:\Users\Credencys\Desktop\qr\app.py", line 99, in retrieve_records
    cursor = conn.cursor()
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Credencys\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection_cext.py", line 676, in cursor       
    self.handle_unread_result(prepared)
  File "C:\Users\Credencys\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection_cext.py", line 932, in handle_unread_result
    raise InternalError("Unread result found")
mysql.connector.errors.InternalError: Unread result found
```

After removing try catch getting following trace and Open-cv is for that i am using this function in a program where open-cv is used.

Comment: Are you quite sure the error comes from this exact code?  Because calling `fetchall` is by itself enough to turn off this error.  `nextset` is unnecessary; you only have one SELECT here.

Comment: Why the OpenCV tag?

Comment: If you comment out the `try` and `except`, where does it fail?  Is it on the `execute` or the `close`?

Comment: Your traceback doesn't have the `buffered=True` parameter.  In any case, are you doing other database accesses before you run this one?  And if your problem isn't related to OpenCV (which it isn't), then don't include the tag.